# Laravel 5.6 Create multiple relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I have a complex question.
I have been working with Laravel for only a week.
And I try to build price lists for customers.

I have 5 tables:

```
price_lists:
  id
  title

---------------------------
price_lists_products:
  id
  product_id
  price_lists_id
  price
  percent

---------------------------
price_lists_users:
  id
  user_id
  price_lists_id

---------------------------
products:
  id
  title
  price
---------------------------
users:
  id
  name
```

And I have to put them together like this:

There are a few price lists

Each price list is associated with products + price

Each user can associate up to 5 price lists

In product view and in the list, I need to show the user the product with the cheapest price that is set for him in the price lists

**For example:**

I have a book that belongs to 5 different price lists and each price list, a different price.

And there is a user associated with 3 price lists.

I want the user to get the cheapest price in the price lists to which he belongs

I hope this is understandable, I have no idea how to approach it, I would be happy if you can help me with it, thanks!

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about the laravel side of things for now, and instead see See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks but it's have to work with Laravel :)

Comment: All in good time. Get a working query first,

Comment: I know how to build it with php and mysql but I saw that in laravel an option of relationships that works really nice and clean, and I would know how to see how I can integrate it with me, the problem is that it seems too complicated relationship for me :(

Comment: Are you asking how to `create` the relations, or how to utilize them?

Comment: Yes how to create the relations

Comment: Read the documentation. If you say you know how to create it in mysql, the wording should be very familiar https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Create models for `Product`, `PriceList` and `User`.

In your `Product` model, create a many-to-many relationship to get related `PriceList` collection:

```
public function pricelists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PriceList')->withPivot('price', 'percent');
    }
```

In your `PriceList` model, create a many-to-many relationship to get related `User` collection:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

Again in the `Product` model, you can get the cheapest price like so:

```
// get the cheapest listing by user_id, you can set default to logged in user
public function cheapestprice($user_id){
    $this->pricelists->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })->orderBy('price_lists_products.price','ASC')->first()->price;
}
```

Finally, with a Product object, you can get the cheapest price:

```
Product::first()->cheapestprice(Auth::user()->id);
```